# Remove input file button and style the files chosen

Tags: html, css, input, image-uploading

I am trying to create an upload form which takes multiple images. I want to be able to *remove* the **"Choose Files"** button but *keep* the **"No file chosen"** to inform the user what files they are going to be uploading.

I understand that I can set the opacity to 0 on the input type file styling, but this removes both the **"Choose Files"** and **"No file chosen"** text.

[Here is the codepen of the image uploader so far.](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpXyZJ)

To summarise:

- I want to **remove** the Choose Files button
- **Keep** the No file chosen text.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="upload">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h1>Would you like to <span style='color: lightgreen;'>Upload</span> or <span style='color: orangered;'>Delete</span> a file?</h1>
                <div style="position: relative; height: 275px;">
                    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="formUp">

                        <input type="file" name="fileToUpload[]" id="fileToUpload" accept="image/*" multiple="multiple"><p>Click here to upload images.</p></input>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload Images" name="submitUpload" />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.up {
    border: none;
}

.upload {
    padding-top: 6%;
}

.upload input[type='file'] {
    outline: none;

    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}

.formUp {
    border: 4px dashed black;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
}

.formUp p {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    line-height: 170px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}

.upload input[type='submit'] {
    margin-top: 2%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
}

.upload input[type='submit'] {
  background: #0AC986;
  dispaly: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
}

.upload input[type='submit']:hover {
    color: #F37272; 
    background-color: palegreen;
}

.upload input[type='submit'] {
    -o-transition: all .3s;
    -moz-transition: all .3s;
    -webkit-transition: all .3s;
    -ms-transition: all .3s;
}

.upload input[type='submit']:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, we can't do much thing to style input file. What we can do is using opacity and appearance trick and makes the input file covering parent element, so user still receive the click event of the input file.

Also you need to use javascript/jQuery to handle what you need. If using javascript/jQuery is not problem for you, below the sample implementation to your [Codepen][1].

```
[1]: http://codepen.io/mahdaen/pen/Ejwodb
```

Comment: Is there a way possible to get rid of the `Click here to upload images.` when images are added? @Nanang

Answer (score 3):

The `text-indent` property will manipulate the position of the **Choose Files** button but leave the **No file chosen** text.

```
    .upload input[type='file']
    {
        text-indent: -999em;
        outline: none;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
    }
```